# Dynamic Required Field Validator

Tags: asp.net

I am creating dynamic controls , I would  like to add required field validator, below is my code, but required field validator is not firing. I am adding control in page_init. Anybody through some light why this code is not functioning. same piece of code is working when I am adding single control. and when I am trying to add multirow control its not working.

```
ctrls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
                ctrls.Add(CreateRequiredFieldValidatorMR(StrControlID.ToString, "Required field."))


Private Function CreateRequiredFieldValidatorMR(ByVal strControlID As String, ByVal ErrorMessage As String) As RequiredFieldValidator
    Return CreateRequiredFieldValidatorMR(strControlID, ErrorMessage, String.Empty)
End Function

Private Function CreateRequiredFieldValidatorMR(ByVal strControlID As String, ByVal ErrorMessage As String, ByVal InitialValue As String) As RequiredFieldValidator
    Dim rfv As New RequiredFieldValidator
    rfv.ID = "ReqVal_" & strControlID
    rfv.ControlToValidate = strControlID
    rfv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic
    rfv.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage
    rfv.InitialValue = InitialValue
    rfv.ValidationGroup = "ReqGrp_" + strControlID
    rfv.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    rfv.Font.Bold = True
    Return rfv
End Function
```

Comment: Wild guess, try changing your ValidatorDisplay to Static instead of Dynamic. I found this page looking for an answer to a problem where using a Dynamic display caused the validator message not to show up at all.

Comment: Nevermind, the message was being correctly set and displayed for me, my issue was that the message was being covered-up.